# How to remove one character from left and one character from right in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have Timezone column and it gives time zone from country.I want remove parenthesis from string how it possible with sql

String is like

```
(GMT)
```

and I want

```
GMT
```

Can any body give me idea?

Comment: Do you want to `UPDATE` or `SELECT`?

Comment: If you only have one set of parentheses, you could also replace them out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want remove the leading and trailing parenthesis in `SELECT` statement

## SELECT

**Using `SUBSTR` :**

`SET @str := '(GMT)';`

```
SELECT 
SUBSTR(@str FROM 2 FOR LENGTH(@str) - 2);
```

**OR**

**Using `REPLACE`:**

```
SET @str := '(GMT)';

SELECT 
REPLACE(REPLACE(@str,')',''),'(','');
```

**OR:**

**Using `TRIM`:**

```
SET @str := '(GMT)';

SELECT 
TRIM(TRAILING ')' FROM TRIM(LEADING '(' FROM @str));
```

**Note:** You have to put your table name while using `SELECT`. Like this:

```
SELECT 
    TRIM(TRAILING ')' FROM TRIM(LEADING '(' FROM YOUR_COLUMN NAME)) FROM YOUR_TABLE;
```

### SQL FIDDLE DEMO

---

## UPDATE

In case you want to update the corresponding columns in your table:

**Using `SUBSTR`:**

```
UPDATE 
YOUR_TABLE
SET YOUR_COLUMN = SUBSTR(YOUR_COLUMN FROM 2 FOR LENGTH(YOUR_COLUMN) - 2);
```

**Using `REPLACE`:**

```
UPDATE 
YOUR_TABLE
SET YOUR_COLUMN = REPLACE(REPLACE(YOUR_COLUMN,')',''),'(','');
```

**Using `TRIM`:**

```
UPDATE 
YOUR_TABLE
SET YOUR_COLUMN = TRIM(TRAILING ')' FROM TRIM(LEADING '(' FROM YOUR_COLUMN));
```

Comment: SELECT  REPLACE(REPLACE(Common_TimeZone.Zone,')',''),'(','') ;
I am getting Unknown Table error while I put column name instead of string variable. Please check it.....

Comment: You have to put your table name there. like this `SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(Common_TimeZone.Zone,')',''),'(','')
FROM YOUR_TABLE;`; Please check the **note** in my answer.

Comment: Any reason behind downvoting? I would love to hear from you (whoever down voted).

Answer (score -1):

Check the [Link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_trim)

```
 $timezone = '(GMT)';
    SELECT TRIM(LEADING '(' FROM '$timezone') AND TRIM(TRAILING ')' FROM '$timezone')
```